# How to reduce the amount of code written when all 'meta' for each view is the same (structure)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Recently I started refacturing/rewriting my code. I noticed that some parts of my code show alot of similarity, and I'm wondering if I could reduce the amount of code required to get the same functionality.

I would like to generate views based on model names I have and give them the same meta attributes where the only difference is the model naming.

Currently I have (in views.py):

```
from finfor import (models, serializers)

class clientOrganizationsListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.clientOrganizations.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.clientOrganizationsSerializer


class financialSystemsListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.financialSystems.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.financialSystemsSerializer
```

As you can see, the only difference between the two is clientOrganizations <> financialSystems.

**I have tried the following:**

```
from finfor import (models, serializers)
from django.apps import apps

for model in apps.get_app_config('finfor').models.values():
    class f'{model}ListCreate'(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = model.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers[f'{model}Serializer']
```

and:

```
from finfor import (models, serializers)
from django.apps import apps

for model in apps.get_app_config('finfor').models.values():
    type(f'{model}Serializer', (generics.ListCreateAPIView, ),
        {'queryset': model.objects.all(),
         'serializer_class': serializers[f'{model}Serializer']
         }
     )
```

I think I'm not using type() properly.

Is there a way to generate the classes by iterating a list ['financialSystems', 'clientOrganizations'] or something similiar?

Comment: You aren't assigning the class returned by `type()` to anything. You could do assign to a dictionary, e.g. `views = {}; view[f'{model}Serializer'] = type(...)`, or assign to globals, e.g. `globals()[f'{model}Serializer'] = type(...)`.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not convinced that the complication of using `type` is worth the reduction in code, unless there are (say) tens of models.

Comment: Thank you Alasdair for your answer. I think you might be right regarding 'type' not being the best way to reduce code, thus other ways are appreciated as well. I have found my answer now, being the answer of Jason Yang. Suggestions are still very appreciated though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from finfor import (models, serializers)
from rest_framework import generics
import re
import importlib

class baseCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    module_path = 'finfor'

    def __init__(self):
        super(baseCreate, self).__init__()
        self.class_name = type(self).__name__
        self.model_name = re.match('(.*)ListCreate', self.class_name).groups()[0]

    def get_queryset(self):
        module = importlib.import_module('%s.models'%self.module_path)
        model = getattr(module, self.model_name)
        return model.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        module = importlib.import_module('%s.serializers'%self.module_path)
        serializer = getattr(module, '%sSerializer'%self.model_name)
        return serializer

class financialSystemsListCreate(baseCreate):
    pass

class clientOrganizationsListCreate(baseCreate):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you Jason for your answer. You have shown me the way.